# In this RL problem, why is the substitution $q_*(A_t)=\mathbb{E}[R_t | A_t] \to R_t $ valid within this expectation (over actions)?

Tags: expected-value, reinforcement-learning, conditional-expectation

The question that follows is from a machine learning textbook (Reinforcement learning Suttion and Barto page 39 [link](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/10-703/textbook/BartoSutton.pdf)).

Given:

- a probability distribution over actions $x$ (a policy) at time $t$ denoted $\pi_t(x)$
- the expected reward, $R_t$, at time $t$ immediately after taking action $a_t$ denoted $q_*(a_t) = \mathbb{E}[R_t | a_t] $.

The following equality is made,
$$\mathbb{E}_{A_t}[(q_*(A_t)-B_t)\frac{\partial\pi_t(x)}{\partial H_t(a)}/\pi_t(A_t)]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}_{A_t}[(R_t-B_t)\frac{\partial\pi_t(x)}{\partial H_t(a)}/\pi_t(A_t)]$$

The authors say that the substitution $q_*(A_t) \to R_t $ is valid as $q_*(A_t)=\mathbb{E}[R_t | A_t]$.
how does this fact permit the above substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equality comes from two properties of conditional expectation:

1. Adam's law:
   $$E_XE[Y|X]=E[Y]$$
   2)"taking out what's known": for any function $h$, $$E[h(X)Y|X] = h(X)E[Y|X]$$

Then $$\mathbb{E}_{A_t}[q_*(A_t)\frac{\partial\pi_t(x)}{\partial H_t(a)}/\pi_t(A_t)]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}_{A_t}[\mathbb{E}[R_t | A_t]\frac{\partial\pi_t(x)}{\partial H_t(a)}/\pi_t(A_t)]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}_{A_t}[\mathbb{E}[R_t \frac{\partial\pi_t(x)}{\partial H_t(a)}/\pi_t(A_t)| A_t]]\hspace{2mm}\text{(by property 2)}$$

$$=\mathbb{E}[R_t \frac{\partial\pi_t(x)}{\partial H_t(a)}/\pi_t(A_t)]\hspace{2mm}\text{(by property 1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you already understood and arrived at $q_*(A_t)=\mathbb{E}[R_t | A_t]$, the next step is to understand $q_*(A_t)$ and $\mathbb{E}[R_t | A_t]$ are actually the same dependent random variable as seemingly differently expressed functions of the same independent random variable $A_t$ here. Finally since you have an outer expectation operator of a function over the distribution of $A_t$, you can simplify $\mathbb{E}[R_t | A_t]$ to the random variable $R_t$ inside the said outer expectation per the famous [law of total expectation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), aka Adam’s law.